# How do I delete a datarow from a datarow array?

Tags: c#, linq, datarow

I am looping through a array of datarows and when a particular random item is not valid I want to remove that item and get the new total to get another random item.
But when I delete a datarow the datarow does not go away... And yes there is probably a much better way to do this but I am not smart enough to do it..

Instead of removing the row I see this inside

`ItemArray = podLps[1].ItemArray` threw an exception of type `System.Data.RowNotInTableException`

```
//PHASE 1: Get all LPs in the pod and add to collection
List<DataRow> allLps = dtLp.AsEnumerable().ToList();
DataRow[] podLps = allLps.Where(x => x.ItemArray[0].ToString() == loPod).ToArray();

//PHASE 2: Pick a random LP from collection that has valid WAVE1
for (int i = podLps.Count(); i > 0; i--)
{
   //Recount items in collection since one may have been removed
   int randomIndex = random.Next(podLps.Count());
   var randomLpUserId = podLps[randomIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString();
   var randomLpWave1 = int.Parse(podLps[randomIndex].ItemArray[2].ToString());

   //Get WAVE1 # for selected LP
   lpNumberOfLoans = GetNumberOfLoans(session, randomLpUserId);

  //check if LP has valid WAVE1 then use this person
   if (randomLpWave1 > lpNumberOfLoans)
   {
       return randomLpUserId;
   }
   else
   {
       podLps[randomIndex].Delete();
   }
}
```

Comment: DataTable allLps = dtLp.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ItemArray[0].ToString() == loPod).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @punkouter working with a DataTable in my example below will do the trick pay attention to how I am assigning the `row variable` this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at this example and it should point you in the right direction for removing rows I just tested it and it works

```
for (int i = myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[i];  //Remove
    if (myDataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString() == string.Empty)
    {
        myDataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I think my confusion stems from thinking a Datarow is not associated with the original datatable. So maybe the best way is to somehow loop through the datatable instead... Or put it all in a list

Comment: I like this answer best since if you convert to a list, then back to an array it will be less efficient than just leaving the data in the DataTable and working with it there.

Comment: Yes. This works. The source data is in a DataTable so it is nice not having to move it into a list or anything.

Comment: Glad that I could quickly see where you were going wrong.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to convert your array of `DataRow[]` to a List, call `RemoveAt` and then convert the list back to an array:

```
 var dest = new List<>(podLps);
 dest.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
 podLps = dest.ToArray();
```

Comment: DataRow [] does not contain a definition RemoveAt

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a List for podLps instead of an array.
Then you can use .RemoveAt as Jaco mentioned (dosn't work for arrays).

DataRow.Delete() just flags the Row to be deleted in the next update of your DataTable.

Comment: You may be right. Perhaps trying to manipulate a list will be easier.